# Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I'm quite rusty with R and SAS, and was given a small project to complete.. for the life of me, I can't quite find the right function or package to do precisely what I've been asked to do.

I have a csv table with ten unique identifiers and five variables (in the same format).

The variables are the presence or not of let's say fruit, for example, in any order with 7 fruits possible for each unique observation.. just five times. There are missing responses for a bunch of them.

So it looks like so:

```
Id v1, v2, v3, v4, v5
1, apple, orange, pear, NA, NA
2, orange, apple, pineapple, NA, strawberry
3, NA, NA, cherry, apple, NA
```

..and so on, down through ten.

I've imported the csv file into R, used melt to change it from wide to long, and now I'm stuck.

I've been asked to create 3 new indicator variables, indicating the presence or absence of three specific fruits at any time for each identifier, then count the total number of IDs that have the three specific fruits at any time.

So I need to count if "apple" and two other fruits, each in their own new dummy variables ever show up in the five variables in any order in ID 1-10. Then I need three separate totals for each fruit with how many IDs total have each of the three fruits present (at any time).

Lastly, I need to visualize the frequencies of those three totals.

Does anyone have any suggestions for packages or functions that can do what I'm looking for?

I'm mostly stuck on the creating the three indicator variables and totaling the ID counts if that helps narrow it down. Any help would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're asking 2 questions, both of which are too broad and don't have any code, and then asking for package suggestions, which is explicitly off-topic. Separate your tasks—analysis, then visualization—and find posts that are already on SO to help. See the guidance on [mcve] questions

Comment: And I'm not asking for anyone to write the code for me. I assumed nobody particularly needed to see the super intro level code I have currently, but I can post it when I get home if it's that important. I was hoping for general suggestions for packages that might be useful. I can handle the visualization. I mostly needed suggestions mostly for the next step.

Comment: `?model.matrix` might be very useful for dummy variables

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot.